# What is KSP date formatting?

Tags: data-mining, date-formatting

I am dealing with a dataset and I have to deal with the date formatting. I need to know different ways I can use this dates feature to predict the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to use this date data. For example, if your date is x implies it is the distance from the 1st of the month. Similarly, it is some distance y months from the first of the year (January).

The day also matters. If the day is Friday => it's 5 days from the week start. You can include this as a different feature.

KSP is another way of reducing the date into a useful feature. Year +(#ofdays from the start of the year -0.5) /#ofdays in the year(356 or 355) leap year or not a leap year.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Can you give an example for this Please